# ProxyPass just displays folder contents of rails app that is running on port 3000

Tags: reverse-proxy, ruby-on-rails, apache2

I have a personal site I'm working on and its the first time I try to configure a server to run multiple apps. So far just getting one to be found through the url instead of with a port number has been a challenge. 
Right now I have an app running on port 3000 in this folder `/var/www/TripItineraryApp`

and I have static content which will be my static html css js site at the default `/var/www/html`

I can actually navigate to `yoanante.com:3000` and hit the app 
but I want to be able to type in `yoanante.com/travelpal` and have the app fully functional with access to its folder structure and routes.

I have tried playing with this for the last 24hours and I've searched everywhere but can't seem to get the settings quite right. I've tried some of the similar answers to similar questions on here to no avail. So any help would really be appreciated.

Here is the 000-default.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html
         ServerName yoanante.com

         ProxyPass /travelpal !
         ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
         ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
         Alias /travelpal /var/www/TripItineraryApp
</VirtualHost>
```

My long term goal is to have my static root site with multiple apps running on different ports that can be accessed through different routes.

```
yoanante.com/app1

yoanante.com/app2
```

etc...

Comment: You have specifically told Apache that `/travelpal` contains only static files and not to pass such requests. All other requests get proxied.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for the quick response. So I removed the lines ProxyPass /travelpal ! and Alias travelpal /var/www/TripItenaryApp and I instead using / for the remaining two I used the route /travelpal all seems good when I do this but once I click anything like sign up or login on the app it tries to go to the root url / followed by 'routename' and I get a 404 not found. I'm trying to stay on /travelpal and have the directories follow it.

Comment: It looks like the the issue is with my app now. I have to change the routes to include the subdirectory /travelpal. You're answer solved my issue. Thanks.